# Set properties for existing artifact in Artifactory Pro from script

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm looking for CLI or Rest API command which allows to set (or update?) properties to artifact with specified GAV and repository name. Is it possible?

The artifact shouldn't be uploaded, it's already there (in Artifactory Maven repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties

Using this REST API you can just add properties on an artifact in Artifactory.